# Problem generating PDF with iText7 version 8.0.1 in a .NET 7.0 Web API

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7, .net-7.0

This is my code

```
   [HttpGet("generar")]
 public IActionResult GenerarPdf()
 {

     // Create a new MemoryStream to write the PDF into it.
     using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         // Create a PDF document using iText 8.
         PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
         PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
         Document document = new Document(pdf);

         // Add content to the PDF.
         document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello, this is a PDF generated from ASP.NET Core with iText 8."));

         // Set the content type in the HTTP response.
         Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=example.pdf"); // Change "inline" to "attachment".
         Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

         // Close the document.
         document.Close();

         // Write the content of the PDF to the HTTP response.
         stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

         // Return the PDF as a file.
         return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
     }
 }
```

The problem arises from the use of document.Close(). If you remove it, the PDF downloads but is corrupt. If you leave it, you get the "Cannot access a closed Stream" exception on this line:

`stream.seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Im pretty sure that is the reason of my problem, but i dont know how to fix it.

iText version: 8.0.1

Comment: As you only do access the stream data using `stream.ToArray()`, you don't need that `stream.seek` call at all. Please try without.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you very much